# Force OData controller to return updated entity back to the client

Tags: entity-framework, odata

I have a sql table which contain a computed column, using entity framework to update an entity create a select statement query after its update statement to return computed column value back to the server. However, the OData controller put and patch methods does not return the updated entity back to the client. They return status code **204 No Content** indeed. since I am showing the computed column in the html view I need to get the updated entity back. is there any approach to force put and patch method to return updated entity back to the client??. It's not reasonable to retrieve the entity again.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Adding a Prefer header will cause the Web API OData stack to return back to you the updated model.

jQuery property for $.ajax call:

```
headers: {
    'Prefer': 'return=representation'
}
```

Comment: Prefer header as stated above solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the OData protocol, 204 should returned for Update method.Is it possible to call "Get" after "Update" to get the computed property?